# How to I make ansible playbook execution to return only value of one variable and nothing more?

Tags: ansible

I do need to load the value of one ansible variable in a bash script and I want to run an ansible playbook that would only print that variable, nothign more.

This is related to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html but apparently I was not able to spot any callback that could be used to achieve that.

Mostly `null` one could be used to silence ansible but this is not solving the output I have.

I know what I could save the variable value to a temp file but I am trying to do this without creating intermediary files, I still have two stream that could be used, stderr and stdout.

Comment: I really think that writing the data out to a temporary file is going to be by far the easiest and most robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are in the right ballpark with the stdout callback, but you may be happier with one of the more programmatically structured ones, so you can reach into the exact task you want and pull out just its output:

```
env ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook the-playbook.yml | \
  jq -r '.plays[0].tasks[0].hosts.localhost.stdout'
```

Here I'm using `jq` because it's great for scripting, but you can, of course, also use an inferior python to do more complex task discovery logic, or better error handling or whatever:

```
env ANSIBLE_STDOUT... | python -c 'import json, sys; o = json.load(sys.stdin); ...'
```